# Does somebody have all ready implemented searchbar on tvos with swiftui?

Tags: swift, swiftui

Does somebody have all ready implemented a search bar using Apple component like UISearchBar with swiftui on tvos ?

I tried this `UISearchBar(frame: .zero)` but I got this error `init(frame:)' is unavailable in tvOS`

I only found solutions for ios.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The scheme of initial setup should be like below. Of course, the logic of searching/filtering/showing results is app specific.

```
import SwiftUI
import TVUIKit

struct SearchView: UIViewControllerRepresentable {

    func makeUIViewController(context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<SearchView>) -> UINavigationController {
        let controller = UISearchController(searchResultsController: context.coordinator)
        controller.searchResultsUpdater = context.coordinator
        return UINavigationController(rootViewController: UISearchContainerViewController(searchController: controller))
    }

    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UINavigationController, context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<SearchView>) {
    }

    func makeCoordinator() -> SearchView.Coordinator {
        Coordinator()
    }

    typealias UIViewControllerType = UINavigationController

    class Coordinator: UIViewController, UISearchResultsUpdating {
        func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {
            // do here what's needed
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var text: String = ""
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            SearchView()
            Spacer()
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Comment: It works thanks, but i can only go to left, do you have this issue too ?

Comment: @asperi this seems it does not conform to a search bar but a search view instead? Do you have a screen shot of what it looks like?

Comment: @MrADOY  did you ever manage to solve the problem with not being able to select letters left of K ? The view is clearly receiving move right gestures, as shown by the key label parallax , but no right movements seem to be accepted.