# SwiftUI Search bar feature searching through an array of structs

Tags: search, swiftui

I want to implement a search bar feature on a listview below is my current code:

```
Section(header: SearchBar(text: self.$searchQuery)) {

            List(fetcher.user) { user in

                HStack() {

                    Text(user.name)

                }

            }

        }
```

where the user is declared as `@Published var user = [User]()`

How do I go about implementing the search feature? I have seen some videos but their use case is much more simpler than mine since I am attempting to perform the searching through an array of structs.

Comment: If you mean *standard* SearchBar then the topic [Does somebody have all ready implemented searchbar on tvos with swiftui?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59729408/12299030) should be helpful - the solution is platform independent actually.

Answer (score 0):

I would use an `ObservableObject` to perform the search logic:

```
class SearchHandler: ObservableObject {
    var searchText: String = "" {
        didSet {
            search()
        }
    }

    // Your array, replace String with your type
    @Published var resultObjs: [String] = []

    // Your initial array, replace String with your type
    var allObjs: [String]

    init(allObjs: [String]) {
        self.allObjs = allObjs
    }

    func search() {
        // Write all your searching code here

        // Use the searchText variable to filter out object
        // from allObjs and write them into resultObjs
    }
}
```

It is a class where you can publish values to listeners, in this case it's going to be your SwiftUI View.

Then you can use it like this:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    // Replace the empty array with your initial data
    @ObservedObject var searchHandler = SearchHandler(allObj: [])

    var body: some View {
        Section(header: SearchBar(text: self.$searchHandler.searchText)) {
            List(self.$searchHandler.$resultObj) { user in
                HStack() {
                    Text(user.name)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```